# How to turn off object-shorthand

Tags: eslint

In .eslintrc.js I have tried:

```
rules: {
    "object-shorthand": "off", //tried 0 aswell
}
```

but I still get

```
error  Expected method shorthand  object-shorthand
```

I want to use a combination of arrow and regular functions but eslint keeps complaining.

Comment: That is how; are you sure that config is getting loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured this out...
Editing .eslintrc.jc rules triggers the hot reload and the app is rebuilt but it seems the settings from eslintrc are not actually applied. If I completely kill the server and restart then the settings work as expected.